# Preventing linux users setting a wrong ownership for files

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I have updated the ownership instead of changing the file permission.

I should have used `chmod 777 <filename>` but used `chown 777 <filename>`.

Example:

```
[john@sv1:/tmp]$ touch etst_test.txt
[john@sv1:/tmp]$ ls -lrt etst_test.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 deploy deploy 0 Oct 17 18:29 etst_test.txt
[john@sv1:/tmp]$ sudo chown 777 etst_test.txt
[john@sv1:/tmp]$ ls -lrt etst_test.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 777 deploy 0 Oct 17 18:29 etst_test.txt
[john@sv1:/tmp]$ vi etst_test.txt
```

I don’t like this happening and I’d like to set some prevention method to stop me/someone by rejecting or showing some errors.

Comment: The usual way to prevent users from breaking their system is to limit sudo access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way for you to do this is move the `chown` command away from the `$PATH` and replace it with a batch file that asks if you really mean to change ownership and if the user answers positively then the batch file executes the corresponding `chown` command.

Of course the downside to this is that once you update the gnu coreutils your batch version of `chown` will be overwritten (depending on your package manager how he responds when he sees a nonstandard version of `chown`).

You could also trust `root` to do the right thing and limit the availability of this command to only `root` by using `chmod` (and be careful to use `chmod` and not `chown` :-) ) on `chown` and then perhaps fiddle around with `sudo` privelages for this command.

Like @qasdfdsaq mentions in the comments then assigning an alias is the best way, that leaves the binary unmodified and wont confuse the package manager. So create a script called `mychown` (or whatever you like) that does the asking, place it in `/usr/local/bin` or someplace like that and have an alias that points `chown` to that script.

Comment: This might be the only way. while there wasnt any other pre-built wrapper available.

Comment: Just assigning an alias is a much better method.